# Visual Studio 15 migrate from X86 to X64 Error in Resource compile

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

When I want do Compile my Resources have the following error

```
error C2039: 'SetDefaultDllDirectories': is not a member of '`global namespace''

Writing STRING:2788,    lang:0x410, size 34
cl /nologo /W4 /GR /EHsc /GF /Gy /DWINVER=0x0501 /D"_MBCS" /D"_AFXDLL" /U"_UNICODE" /Fo"Debug/" /Fd"Debug/" /FD /MDd /Od /D"WIN32" /I"D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\NmsBuild\Include" /I"D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\Ms\Include" /I"D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\Mf\Include" /I"D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\PlatformSDK\Include" /D"_DEBUG" "Debug\NmsLib_LANG.cpp" /link /NOLOGO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MACHINE:I386 /base:0x13600000 /version:1.1 /incremental:no /map:"Debug\NmsLib_LANG.map" /dll /out:"D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\Bin\Debug\.\NmsLib_LANG.dll" /libpath:"D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\Mf\Lib" /libpath:"D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\Ms\Lib" /libpath:"D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\PlatformSDK\Lib" "Debug\NmsLib_LANG.res" 
NmsLib_LANG.cpp
D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\Mf\Include\afx.h(38): warning C4996: 'MBCS_Support_Deprecated_In_MFC': MBCS support in MFC is deprecated and may be removed in a future version of MFC.
D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\Mf\Include\afx.h(33): note: see declaration of 'MBCS_Support_Deprecated_In_MFC'
d:\home\atiras\v77ma_64bit_branch001\bindll\ms\include\sal_supp.h(57): warning C4005: '__useHeader': macro redefinition
D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\Ms\Include\sal.h(2866): note: see previous definition of '__useHeader'
d:\home\atiras\v77ma_64bit_branch001\bindll\ms\include\specstrings_supp.h(77): warning C4005: '__on_failure': macro redefinition
D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\Ms\Include\sal.h(2876): note: see previous definition of '__on_failure'
D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\Mf\Include\atlcore.h(644): error C2039: 'SetDefaultDllDirectories': is not a member of '`global namespace''
D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\Mf\Include\atlcore.h(644): error C2065: 'SetDefaultDllDirectories': undeclared identifier
D:\Home\Atiras\V77Ma_64Bit_Branch001\BinDll\Mf\Include\atlcore.h(646): error C2065: 'LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32': undeclared identifier
```

I have defined `_USING_V110_SDK71_` but that does not seams to work on Resource Compiling

Comment: Are you sure this is compiling the resources not 'NmsLib_LANG.cpp' ? I can't imagine you'd include afx.h in a resource compilation.

Comment: It was  the linking of the different languages off the resources  which was a genrated Code  an in this spe piels of Code the   _USING_V110_SDK71_ wa missing

Comment: You are setting `WINVER` to 0x0501, i.e. Windows XP. [SetDefaultDllDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories) is not available on Windows XP. Your issue has nothing to do with switching from x86 to x64. Your issue is likely, that your x86 and x64 project configurations do not match.